# binaries of Java jai-imageio library for Mac available somewhere

Tags: java

Are the binaries of Java jai-imageio library for Mac available somewhere? 
http://java.net/projects/jai-imageio

or did someone manage to compile it for Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Juts a quote from wiki

> JAI is provided as a free download directly from Sun Microsystems for the Windows, Solaris, and Linux platforms. **Apple Inc. provides a Mac OS X version** of the API from their website for Mac OS X v10.3; Mac OS X v10.4 ships with it **preinstalled**.

Path to JAI `/System/Library/Java/Extensions`

Comment: Apple will not be updating their version of Java beyond 1.6. Many have already moved to using Java 1.7 provided by Oracle. Support and compatibility for these native extensions going forward is... questionable.